# Delete message if the 'no no word' is in it - discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want the bot to delete a message if the 'no no word' (anything in `nono`) is in it, but it should delete only if ***only*** that word is sent.

Example: the 'no no word' is "Hate", but if I send "I Hate you", it shouldn't delete the message. It should delete only if I send *only* "Hate" (without the "I" and "you" before and after it).
Here is my code:

```py
nono = ['Hate']

@client.event
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages = False)
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.id == client.user.id:
        return
    
    if message.guild is not None:
        for word in nono:
            if word in message.content:
                await message.delete()
                await message.author.send('I hate you too')

                await client.process_commands(message)
            else : 
                return
```

Comment: Why do you use `@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages = False)` for an event? It all works fine for me. The bot deletes `I Hate you`  but not `I hate you`, maybe that is your mistake.

Comment: weird.... And i use ```@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages = False)``` for an event is bcos I want the message to not be deleted for ppl who have manage message permission only

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure that you wrote "I Hate you" and not "I hate you" in your message?

I have built a minimal example according to your code and it works fine.

```py
nono = ['Hate']
message = "I hate you"

for word in nono:
    m = message.upper()
    if word.upper() in m:
        print("delete")
    else:
        print("Nothing")
```

I also recommend you to upper case your strings so that your detection is not case sensitive.

Comment: Yea... I write it "I Hate you" and not "I hate you" plus I also tried using the upper and lower thing but it also didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Try using a json file, I've personally made a few automod bots and all of them use json.

Here's an example:

```
 @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        user = message.author
        guild_id = message.guild.id

        em = discord.Embed(title="Profanity filter", description="Please refrain from using blacklisted words!", color=magenta)
        em.set_footer(text=user.name, icon_url=user.avatar_url)
        em.set_author(name=message.guild.name, icon_url=message.guild.icon_url)
        
        with open(f"json/{guild_id}/blacklist.json", 'r') as f:
            badwords = json.load(f)

        if any(word in message.content.lower() for word in badwords):
            await message.delete()
            return await message.channel.send(embed=em)
```

It reads the json file that's in the folder with the name corresponding to the discord guild ID. If the word is in that file it deletes it.

This is what the json file would look like:

```
{
"test": {
    "test": "test"
},
"test": {
    "test2": "test2"
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**
My friend has figured it out. Basically, this is the code from him:

```py
nono ['Hate']

for word in nono:
    if message.content.lower().find(word)!=-1:
        await message.delete()
        await message.author.send("I hate you too dummy!")
```

Kudos to him :D

Comment: Are you positive any message method should work after `message.delete()`?

Comment: Dunno. Im new to python and that ```message.delete()``` works for me so I got no complain

Answer (score 0):

You most probably are looking for [the `==` operator](https://www.w3schools.com/python/trypython.asp?filename=demo_oper_compare1):

```py
nono = ['Hate']

@client.event
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages = False)
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.id == client.user.id:
        return
    
    if message.guild is not None:
        for word in nono:
            if word == message.content: #If the message's content is EXACTLY and ONLY the word
                author = message.author 
#Storing the message's 'author' in this variable as 'message.author.send()' probably won't work 
#as mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70290260/discord-py-delete-message-if-the-no-no-word-is-in-it/70290501#comment124313432_70307898
                await message.delete()
                await author.send('I hate you too')

                await client.process_commands(message)
            else : 
                return
```

You used `in` instead of `==`. `==` checks if the LHS (Left Hand Side) is the same as the RHS (Right Hand Side). `in` in `if word in message.content:` checks if the LHS (`word`) is *somewhere* in the RHS (`message.content`) and *doesn't bother if there's something other than/after/before/with the LHS* unlike `==`.